# Word/phrase that indicates (unofficially) satisfying responsibilities of another position

Tags: phrase-requests

I'm working to upgrade my resume with some recent contractual software development I've done. I was the lead developer on a project with a small team, so while my main responsibility was writing code for the project, I also would like to highlight my organizational efforts in adhering to Agile/Scrum processes. Something along the lines of:

> **Software Development Lead (Contract)**
>
> - Designed intuitive web interface for ...
> - Developed responsive and scalable backend service using ...
> - "Effectively acted as" Project Manager/Scrum Master by ...

I don't want to give the impression that I was actually hired as a project manager, however. I'm looking for a strong verb or verb phrase to replace "effectively acted as" which conveys the fact that I (successfully) assumed the responsibilities of the role while not officially holding the role's title. I thought of "performed duties of Project Managed/Scrum Master by...", but this still feels too clunky and I'd prefer something more eloquent.

Comment: Although I wouldn't recommend it for a resume, you could say that you did **double duty** as something else. Another phrase is that you were **seconded** to another role. Or, if outside of your pay, you **volunteered** to do something.

Comment: But, to paraphrase what you wrote in your question, you could simply put **acted as**  and leave out "effectively" altogether. Somebody who reads "effectively" can take it as a negative comment about the person actually in the role. (Without using "effectively," it's assumed that the role was temporarily vacant.)

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using the term, [provisional](https://www.etymonline.com/word/provisional).

*Etymonline*

> **provisional** (adj.) "as a temporary arrangement for the present," c. 1600, from provision (n.) + -al (1), or else from Middle French provisionnal (15c.), from Old French provision. The notion is of something that will "provide for present needs."
>
> Related: **Provisionally**.

- **Provisional** Project Manager/Scrum Master by ...
- Acted **provisionally** as Project Manager/Scrum Master by ...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the Latin term [de facto](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/de%20facto) (MW adjective definition 1)

> actual; especially : being such in effect though not formally recognized
>
> - has become the movement's *de facto* spokesperson